# HTML5 layer multiple dropzones

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to layer multiple dropzones but I want only the "highest" one to call the ondrop-function. I've tried doing that by giving one layer a higher a z-index but still the function gets called multiple times when dropping the file into an area where both dropzones (in my case div tags) are layered.
How can I prevent this? I want the function to be called only once.
This is my (example) code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
   <meta charset='UTF-8'>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="z-index: 0; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;" ondrop="drop_upload(event)" ondragover="return false">
    <div style="z-index: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black;" ondrop="drop_upload(event)" ondragover="return false">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function drop_upload(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
        alert(event.dataTransfer.files[0].name);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your file, as one `<div>` is a child of another, the event [bubbles](http://lucybain.com/blog/2014/event-bubbling/) from child to parent unless you prevent that with

```
 event.stopPropagation();
```

On the other hand, organising the `<div>`s one inside the other prevents `z-index` from having any effect. The "inner" div is always "above" the "outer" in the sense that any mouse event happening grafically over the inner div will be dispatched to it before it bubbles to the outer div.

If you would like to change that order, you must use absolutely positioned `<div>`s that are siblings in the DOM tree, but grafically one on top of the other:

```
<body>
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 300px; height: 300px; background-color: green;" ondrop="drop_upload(event)" ondragover="return false">
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 200px; height: 200px; background-color: black;" ondrop="drop_upload(event)" ondragover="return false">
  </div>
</body>
```

Like this, the `ondrop` event function will only be executed once, since no elements that have that attribute are in a parent-child relationship.